# Displaying a Single Field from Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public class StudentViewModel
    {
        public Student studentVm { get; set; }
        public StudentAdditionalInfo studentAdditionalInfoVm { get; set; }

        public int rcImgToProcess { get; set; }     
    }
```

`studentVm` and `studentAdditionalInfoVm` stores the data of my 2 Tables `Student` and `StudentAdditionalInfo`, these contains multiple records

`rcImgToProcess` store the data of the record count that I passed from my controller, so it is only a single data (I can use ViewBag but for some reason I prefer passing it to Model)

```
<div>
    I want the value of [rcImgToProcess] here
</div>

@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.studentVm.Id  </td>
            <td>@item.studentVm.StudentCourse</td>
            <td>@item.studentAdditionalInfoVm.MotherName</td>
            <td>@item.studentAdditionalInfoVm.FatherName</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Controller

```
int rcImgToProcess = "0";

rcImgToProcess= 1001;

var studentList = from s in student
    join st in studentAdditionalInfo on s.Id equals st.Id into st2
    from st in st2.DefaultIfEmpty()

    select new StudentViewModel {
       studentVm = s,
       studentAdditionalInfoVm = st,
       rcImgToProcess = rcImgToProcess
    };

return View(studentList);
```

How can I call `rcImgToProcess` to display on the header part of the page

Comment: You can just use `<div>@Model.rcImgToProcess</div>` (although you can also use `@Model.Count()` instead of adding that property to your model)

Comment: Error `''object' does not contain a definition for 'rcImgToProcess''`

Comment: Sorry, the first one should be inside the loop (but if you actually want the count of `StudentViewModel` then use the 2nd option - but its no clear what `rcImgToProcess` is for - you seem to imply that its the count of the items in the collection)

Comment: I need to pass it to my Model because I am not only passing the count, Im passing also some other variable. I cant use the 2nd option because its only for Count

Comment: Sorry, that make no sense. Show your GET method so we can understand what it is you property is for

Comment: Check my edit, I added part of my Controller code

Comment: Since your model is a collection, then it makes no sense to keep repeating that value for each item in the collection. You need a 'parent' view model that contains `int rcImgToProcess` and `IEnumerable<StudentViewModel> Students` (you could of course also use `<div>@Model.First().rcImgToProcess</div>` but that would be crazy)

Comment: can you provide a sample code adding a parent viewmodel to my existing code

Comment: `public class MyViewModel { public int int rcImgToProcess { get; set; } public IEnumerable<StudentViewModel> Students { get; set; } }` and pass that model to the view

Comment: How I will pass the data from controller to the model? I am calling my vew this way `return View(studentList);` to pass the data from my existing ViewModel, I dont know how to pass 2 ViewModel to my View

Comment: What? Its just one view model as per my previous comment. `var model = new MyViewModel{ rcImgToProcess = 1001, Students = studentList }; return view(model)` and then `<div>@Model.rcImgToProcess</div>` and `foreach(var item in Model.Students) { .... }`

Comment: Im getting the same error

Comment: Then you did not do it correctly!

Answer (score 0):

are you referencing the `StudentViewModel` in the view correctly?

you should have `@model <namespaceForStudentViewModel>.StudentViewModel` at the top of the file.

eg `@model SampleApplication.ViewModels.StudentViewModel`

then you can use `<div>@Model.rcImgToProcess</div>` anywhere in the view

Comment: Im not but I can display all the other fields without problem

Comment: how are you passing the model to the view? in the controller action. Also try referencing it and see if that works